# Is keeping data ON eats data memory in android?

Tags: android

In android mobiles or general laptops,keeping data ON eats up the internet data memory little bit?for example ,if I kept my internet data ON in my android for one day mean,does it eats about 1MB of data without using internet for the whole day?
If not,how can a mobile phone detects that it gets 3G internet or 4G internet or 2G internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked 2 questions:

> Do keeping network DATA `connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);` on consumes bandwitch and could I be charged for it?

Yes. Any system could use this connection to do any action that requires network. Most programs try to check for Wi-Fi only... but if a connection is made available, then it can be used (and could cost you money, its in the INTERNET permission you granted to the APP)

> how can a mobile phone detects that it gets 3G internet or 4G internet or 2G internet?

Android has a [system that allow programmers](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html) to check what kind of connection is available at the moment, and even ask the user to enable it for a moment, or request to switch it on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you keep data ON its consuming your data because there are lot of system process and application process running in background which keeps on polling to servers which eats little data.